# How to handle repeating view element with backbone-stickit

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-stickit

What is the best way to do a bindings for a repeating view element?

Here is a view fragment currently implemented with *underscore* template.
How can I replace this block with *backbone.stickit* ?

```
<% _.forEach(model.estimates, function(estimate) { %>
         <li class="list-item span12">
              <span id='estimateNo'><%= estimate.estimateNo %></span>
              <span id='name'><%= estimate.name %></span>
              <span id='validity'><%= estimate.validity %></span>
              <span id='grossPrice'><%= estimate.grossPrice %></span>
              <span id='status'><%= estimate.status %></span>
         </li>
<% }) %>

bindings: {
    '#estimateNo': ???,
    '#name': ???,
    '#validity': ???,
    '#grossPrice': ???,
    '#status': ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question...
there is a design issue with my view, i should move the content of the loop into a sub-view and use stickit for each individual view.

The loop should be in the code and not in the template ...